# C Pointer to Pointer - Access string list

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to access array of strings via pointers. It seems to be working fine when memory is alocated but somehow the values are lost if i try to iterate the pointer again. However, the pointed addresses are correct.

```
char **rows = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //first time
    *(rows + i) = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    sprintf(*(rows + i), "0x10%d", i);
    printf("---%s@0x%x", *(rows + i), (rows + i));

}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //second time
    printf("++++%s@0x%x", *(rows + i), (rows + i));
}
```

Output Format : value@address

Above (first loop) will produce following output:

```
---0x100@0x1007e0
---0x101@0x1007e8
---0x102@0x1007f0
---0x103@0x1007f8
---0x104@0x100800
```

Which is correct interms of values and corresponding addresses. But somehow the values are lost when i try to use them again, below is the output from second loop:

```
++++@0x1007e0
++++0@0x1007e8
++++0x102@0x1007f0
++++0x103@0x1007f8
++++0x104@0x100800
```

As its plain to see that address are correct for all five nodes, but values for starting nodes are missing.

Question:

Why values are missing at address  0x1007e0 and 0x1007e8 with valid address?

Thanks,

Comment: I wonder if you really meant: `char **rows = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 8);` -- allocating 8 char pointers, rather than 8 chars.

Comment: #mah Thanks and that was the problem. I wonder how come still it was showing some values! Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @user2492889 That's undefined behavior: the crash or overwrites do not need to happen, your program could have even worked all the way, if malloc was a bit more generous at allocating extra memory  beyond what you've asked.

Comment: Even though you've allocated too small a region for your needs, the memory still exists so you're able to use it. Since you don't own it though (something else in your application does), using it leads to undefined results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may have to do with your code not allocating enough space for the pointers: since you are allocating eight pointers, not eight characters, this line

```
char **rows = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
```

should be

```
char **rows = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 8);
```

Making this change fixes the problem ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/B6tmuQ)).

Comment: How about `char **rows = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 8);`. No casting of malloc return, and I personally prefer `void*` just because it's easy to distiguish that it's pointer size being refered to.

Comment: @jite my preference for the size would actually be `malloc(sizeof(*rows));` -- this is a general pattern I follow to enable a change of a variable's type to not interfere with allocations (though of course changing from one pointer type to another is not a change in size).

Comment: @Jite That's right, it's C, not C++, so there's no need to cast. I copy-pasted from the OP, so I kept the cast, but it it indeed not necessary.

Comment: If you're accessing the allocation as `char*`, then they should be allocated as `malloc(8 * sizeof(char *))`. Of course, on nearly all platforms pointers are all the same size, but that's not guaranteed by the spec. `(void *)` will work as well, but might be allocating more than necessary.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You're right, I put `char*` first, but then quickly edited to `char**`, which was of course incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: @mah I agree with you about using the variables instead of fixed types in most cases. In this case though I prefer `void*` for readability. I take it as unlikely that you wouldn't need to refactor a lot more when switching from pointer-to-pointer to pure pointer, so I feel that the pros of using `*var` might not apply here. `void*` on the other hand explicitly tells you that it is pointer size you are after. My personal thoughts :)